# Group By, Rank and aggregate spark data frame using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
A     B    C
---------------
A1    B1   0.8
A1    B2   0.55
A1    B3   0.43

A2    B1   0.7
A2    B2   0.5
A2    B3   0.5

A3    B1   0.2
A3    B2   0.3
A3    B3   0.4
```

How do I convert the column 'C' to the relative rank(higher score->better rank) per column A? Expected Output:

```
A     B    Rank
---------------
A1    B1   1
A1    B2   2
A1    B3   3

A2    B1   1
A2    B2   2
A2    B3   2

A3    B1   3
A3    B2   2
A3    B3   1
```

The ultimate state I want to reach is to aggregate column B and store the ranks for each A:

Example:

```
B    Ranks
B1   [1,1,3]
B2   [2,2,2]
B3   [3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Add rank:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

ranked =  df.withColumn(
  "rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("A").orderBy(desc("C"))))
```

Group by:

```
grouped = ranked.groupBy("B").agg(collect_list(struct("A", "rank")).alias("tmp"))
```

Sort and select:

```
grouped.select("B", sort_array("tmp")["rank"].alias("ranks"))
```

Tested with Spark 2.1.0.

Comment: Where is the favourite button?

Answer (score 2):

```py
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("col2")
ranked = demand.withColumn("col_rank", row_number().over(windowSpec))
ranked.show(1000)
```