# Rank a grouped data datetime column and find difference between the subsequent ranks

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dense-rank

I have a data with grouped columns on product name and date. I now want to rank the product_purchased column which is datetime. And then subtract between the subsequent ranks to get the date difference and aggregate on the subtracted value column.

```
Prod Name Hour 
 A         20
 B         13
 C         17
 A         20
 B         12
```

After group by the df would look like

```
Prod Name Hour Count
   A      20    2
   B      13    1
   C      17    1
   B      12    1
```

aggs_date = load.groupBy("product_name", "hour").agg((count("*").alias("cnt")),(F.rank('date_logged').alias('rank'))

```
load.select('date_logged').show(20,False)
+---------------------------+
|date_logged                |
+---------------------------+
|2018-06-12 05:38:00.0000000|
|2018-08-20 17:15:00.0000000|
|2018-08-20 20:40:00.0000000|
|2018-08-14 06:39:00.0000000|
|2018-06-23 06:32:00.0000000|
|2018-05-22 09:33:00.0000000|
```

What I want is that the groups should have a rank and then the product_purchased column should be subtracted with the previous rank (Rank 1 - Rank 2) and give days difference. And further aggregations on the difference column.

What is the approach to solve this?

```
ranked =  load.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("product_name").orderBy(desc("product_purchased"))))
grouped = ranked.groupBy("hour", "product_name").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("rank")).alias("tmp"))
```

It looks like:

```
 grouped.show()
+----+------------------------+--------------------+                            
|hour|primary_application_name|                 tmp|
+----+------------------------+--------------------+
|   0|                 E-RE   |[[10], [238], [23...|
|   0|    ACQU...             |[[55], [71], [72]...|
|   0|     MOBILE MESSA...    |               [[2]]|
|   0|                    JADE|[[21], [75], [134...|
|   0|                  p2    |      [[114], [174]]|
|   1|     ACQU...            |[[18], [19], [54]...|
|   1|     MOBILE MESSA...    |               [[3]]|
|   1|                    JADE|[[19], [20], [74]...|
|   2|                 E-RE   |[[6], [236], [236...|
|   2|     DATA ACQU...       |[[265], [305], [7...|
|   2|                    JADE|[[42], [66], [73]...|
|   2|    LM RAT...           |               [[3]]|
|   3|    VULNERAB...         |[[42], [52], [65]...|
|   3|    WE...               |               [[3]]|
```

I want to find the date difference between the ranks (238-10),(239-238)..so on.

Comment: Question a bit unclear. Please specify what you want to rank by. Can you also include in your examples more complete DataFrames representing your input and desired output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661068/group-by-rank-and-aggregate-spark-data-frame-using-pyspark

You can add ranks using window functions. Then, you have ranked data. From there it is a cake walk.

Comment: @Prazy I followed the answer from the link. But after I get the ranks how do i proceed to subtract the dates with respect to the ranks in the group?

Comment: @GalSivan I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you edit the question so that the DataFrame with dates and ranks look aligned?

Comment: @Prazy I have further edited the question.