# Convert rank() partition by oracle query to pyspark sql

Tags: oracle, pyspark

How to convert below rank() partition by oracle sql query to equivalent pyspark sql.

```sql
SELECT department_id,
       last_name,
       salary,
       commission_pct,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department_id
                    ORDER BY salary DESC, commission_pct) "Rank"
FROM   employees
WHERE  department_id = 80;
```

Comment: Have you tried running this query in spark-sql? Did you get an error? The wrong output? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: There are no errors, looking for a way to re-write using UDF's or dataframe functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use window functions in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857863/how-to-use-window-functions-in-pyspark)

Comment: I have founded this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661068/group-by-rank-and-aggregate-spark-data-frame-using-pyspark Maybe it will help... Also this article: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html Cheers!